# How to start working on as3yaml?

Tags: apache-flex, yaml

I am a newbie in yaml but I have to work on as3yaml which I don't have any knowledge on it.

I already downloaded as3yaml and attached to my project which is Flex project and I already read about yaml syntax.
But I don't have any ideas how can I start to work on it. I don't know how to new .yaml file with eclipse. I can't find any .yaml new file.
For now I understand that I have to create .yaml file and have to write the function on Actionscript Class to encode/decode the .yaml file.

And I also need some get started websites which I can learn myself.

Pls help!

Comment: Can I ask why you're using yaml instead of say AMF?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Yaml as well, however it seems pretty straightforward:

```
var yaml:YAML = new YAML();
var data:Object = YAML.decode(yourYamlString);
```

You should really try reading [the docs](http://as3yaml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/org/as3yaml/YAML.html).  Also, I wouldn't recommend using YAML unless you really have to.  If you can, use AMF (native, faster, parses directly into model) but if you want something a little more 'web standardized' you can use JSON with the as3core library to parse it.

Comment: Yes, I already read the doc but I don't know which part of codes where should be placed. And I also don't know how can I run to test.

Comment: ...that is a more basic concept and another problem altogether.  I suggest you read more on basic Flex functionality.